How to code an algorithm for Linda Index calculation in SQL (Apache Superset)?
I collided with a real obstacle trying to bring the calculation of Linda index in Apache Superset SQL Notebook. Let's assume we have a table for 6 firms in one region for one year with their market share values:
CREATE TABLE t0
(
  region_name varchar(30),
  firm_name varchar(30),
  report_date date,
  share_f int
  );
 INSERT INTO t0 VALUES
('NY', 'Apex', 2024, 18),
('NY', 'Indit', 2024, 12),
('NY', 'Root', 2024, 11),
('NY', 'Bias', 2024, 8),
('NY', 'Fare', 2024, 7),
('NY', 'Latan', 2024, 6);

I have to use this formula, where we consider n=4 for our case: Linda Index formula
So, as I see my steps should be:

To put firms in descending order by the value of share;
To calculate the sum of CRn (first 4 values of shares from the top) that is going to be constant;
To start calculating the sum of CRi for same values of shares from the top (from i=1 to i=?) till the moment when LI(i+1) becomes greater than LI(i).

The problem is that I cant make a cycle that launches correctly the 3rd step (Just to note: I cant avoid the cycle and just calculate Index straightly, because the real table contains many years and regions, so it's needed to unify the calculation for different conditions).
After ordering the table in descending way I thought I have to assign numbers for values via ROW_NUMBER to calculate CR(n) sum for top-4 values correctly. In case of cycle I intended to make something with WHILE function, however I don't even imagine the way it should be implemented.
